# APM is not connecting to Kibana through angular

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, angular-cli, kibana

We are using angular CLI version **15.0.3.**

The library added: **@elastic/apm-rum-angular**

**Configuration:**

```
 this.apm = service.init({
    serviceName: 'abc',
    serverUrl: '....'      
 });
```

```
this.apm .setUserContext({
   'username':name,
   'id': name
});
```

The application running successfully but it does not show in **APM -> Services** in Kibana Elastic.

Here in this library not providing an option for **secret-token**.

Can anyone please suggest what I missed here and how can I set secret-token or package?

Comment: Since RUM runs in the user's browser the secret token makes no sense. Have you been through the [troubleshooting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/rum-js/current/troubleshooting.html) guide?